# How to communicate between WP7 and Android (any library?)

Tags: android, wifi, windows-phone-7.1, communication

I want to create multi-player game on local WIFI network between mobile devices. WP has a NetworkSession object, which can handle communication (especially game communication), but only between WP devices (of course). Is there any library, that is good alternative to this NetworkSession and supports also WP-Android communication? Im true "newbie" in this domain, therefore i cannot find any. Or is there only one solution - communicate between WP and And. only with Sockets some how? Thanks for answers a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UDP to send and receive data on both the sides. I will provide you with links to the Windows side.

[Example Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286407%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[Sockets Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[Multiplayer Game Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickyt/archive/2011/06/15/windows-phone-peer-to-peer-multiplayer-game-using-sockets-in-xna.aspx)

The last one is particularly useful to you. You can easily find similar examples for Android.